# How do I output to the console, and overwrite text without clearing the screen and re-writing everything?

Tags: c++, linux, macos

Like when using aircrack-ng, or any program that has tables of data that constantly update.

=\

Comment: In standard C++ there is no way to do this.

So the question becomes what platform are you building on.  
Each platform has libraries that help you do this.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want, but printing the character '\r' deletes the line the cursor is in. Useful for progress indicators or something like that.

Comment: Sounds like you want to draw randomly all over the terminal.  As Martin mentioned, there's no standard way to do this, but [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends somewhat on the system, and above all, how much you want to overwrite.  For a lot of simply programs, outputting `'\r'` will do the trick: it will return the cursor to the start of the line (on almost all consoles), and you can overwrite the line.  (I've used this in the past for continuously updated progress reports: `n records processed`, for example.  Just be sure to not output a `'\n'` until you're ready.

For anything more complex, the usual solution is the `curses` library.  It should be present on most Unix (sometimes under the name `ncurses`), and there's a port of `ncurses` to Windows as well.  (The generic name of the library, and its name under traditional Unix, is `curses`; `ncurses` is a GPL implementation the library.)